# Where do I get the Fart in a Jar?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

There's an achievement called **Stay Classy Steelport** which reads as follows: `Kill 25 Gang Members each with 'the Penetrator' AND the Fart in a Jar.`

I've had The Penetrator for a long time, but I've completed Act 2 and I've still seen no sign of the Fart in a Jar. Where do I find this weapon? Is it a mission reward? I haven't seen it as a weapon to purchase in Friendly Fire either.

Comment: Fart in a Jar is also one of the taunt options, and I thought you had to taunt someone to death with it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://saintsrow.com/community/go/thread/view/136781/28695261/?pg=last):

> To get Fart in a Jar, upgrade flashbangs to LV4. Gets rid of the
>   Flashbangs, though.

you can also mod it using horizon

Comment: I almost never use Flashbangs so I hadn't even looked at the upgrades for them in the store! I wouldn't have expected them to upgrade into that.

Comment: I upgraded mine to level 4, but did not notice that in the description.

Comment: My mistake, I only did to level 3 when I thought I did it to 4. The change is quite obvious at that point. ;)